# How do I scan values from a row except the first one

Tags: c, arrays, struct, scanf

Say I am given a row
 
    D 143 189 123
    D 123 120 122
    F 111 234 221

How can I scan only the values in the first two row and not letter and also exclude the scan of the third row.

My version

```
typedef struct{
    int Maths;
    int Comp;     
    int Eng;
}Marks;

Marks A[99]; // Struct 
int row = 0;

while(c = getchar()){
    if(c == 'D'){
        scanf("%d %d %d", A[row].Maths, A[row].Comp, A[row].Eng);
        row++;
    }
}
```

Comment: `A[row].Maths` --> `&A[row].Maths`

Answer (score 1):

Adding a `*` in front of the format specifier means that you want to read from the stream, but the result should be discarded and not stored in a location pointed to in an argument.

```
if(c == 'D'){
    scanf("%d %d %d", &A[row].Maths, &A[row].Comp, &A[row].Eng);
    row++;
}
else {
    scanf("%*d %*d %*d");
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d %d %d", A[row].Maths, A[row].Comp, A[row].Eng);` --> `scanf("%d %d %d", &A[row].Maths, &A[row].Comp, &A[row].Eng);`

Comment: @CoolGuy Thanks, I didn't catch that. I just assumed that his original code was correct (which was a bad assumption).